# javascript, regexp - wrap color values in span

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I want all the CSS color values in my `<code>` element to be wrapped in span tags.

So this:

```
<code id="colorful-css">
body {
    color: black;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0cf;
}
#box {
    outline: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
    background: hsla(235, 85%, 43%,.5);
}
</code>
```

would become this:

```
<code id="colorful-css">
body {
    color: <span class="css-color">black</span>;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: <span class="css-color">#0cf</span>;
}
#box {
    outline: 1px solid <span class="css-color">rgb(255,0,0)</span>;
    background: <span class="css-color">hsla(235, 85%, 43%,.5)</span>;
}
</code>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It'd be easy to match the hex colors, rgb, and hsla, but the named colors could be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to parse CSS fully and thus don't mind some possible mistakes (comments, quotes, etc), you could use an expression like:

```
#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b|\b(?:rgba?|hsla?)\([^()]+\)|\b(?:red|blue|list|of|valid|color|names|...)\b
```

Expanded as needed.

Comment: That looks good, but I can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/wBxFb/1/ In Chrome I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Web_Designer, in JS you quote regex like `var re = /expression/i;`, to replace all you use `/g` also. See http://jsfiddle.net/wBxFb/2/ for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You need a syntax highlighter for that. I'm not an expert at coding but you could use some plugin like [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Comment: I already use Google code prettify, But it doesn't wrap spans around CSS color values.